# How to check for multiple hidden network SSIDs?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have 10 identical devices (snappy ubuntu core is the OS,although any suggestions Windows or OS independent [eg. source code] are welcome) in the same room. Every device has an identical list of 10 hidden network SSIDs and password combinations. When turned on, they automatically search for any of these hidden SSIDs (simply by attempting to connect to each SSID in the list in order, or is there a genuine way to search for hidden SSIDs?). The search is repeated (if necessary) until a hidden SSID is not found, in which case the device creates the hidden network using the SSID it was unable to find from the list. Thus:

1. Device 1 is turned on and searches for SSID 1 in the list. It does
   not find it, so creates a hidden network with the details of SSID 1
   in the list.
2. Device 2 is turned on and searches for SSID 1 in the list. As Device
   1 has created this hidden network already, Device 2 detects this and
   continues to search for a hidden SSID not in use (it searches for
   SSID 2 list). As it does not find this SSID in use, it creates this
   hidden network.

The devices cannot be individually programmed to create a network using one of 10 SSIDs on the list - the point here is that identical devices are capable of finding an SSID on the list that is not in use without user input.

So far my research has found a script that attempts to connect to an SSID:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Automatically try to connect to 'MyWiFi' when WiFi is enabled
#

# the output of nmcli should be in English
LC_ALL=C

# loop for a while until NetworkManager is accepting commands
while [ "$(nmcli -t -f WIFI,STATE nm)" = 'enabled:disconnected' ]
do
 nmcli con up id MyWiFi
 sleep 5
done

exit 0
```

How could I adapt this for the purposes described above?

Comment: Hidden SSIDs are a waste of time: when someone (legally) connects to a hidden SSID network,  the SSID must be sent in clear text. So, If I want to find out the name of a hidden-SSID network, all I need to do is to send out a `deauth` packet to someone currently connected to the network, and listen to authorization, where the SSID will be presented in clear text.  There goes your privacy. Same thing with MAC filter:  hidden SSIDs and MAC filter provide **no** security of any sorts.

Comment: Oh I know, this isn't for security sake, it's simply for convenience. We already have a couple of wifi networks accessible from the room, adding another 10 (none of which will be used by people) would just create more headaches for staff trying to get on the wifi networks and subsequently the IT department.

Comment: Ok, but now answer this question: `pcN` wakes up, detects `j` hidden networks, how does it know which one, in the list it has, is up and which one is down? In other words, how can it identify the `up` SSIDs, if they are hidden, and of course we do not wish to `deauth` anyone?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand - which is entirely possible - the hidden SSID networks would always be up, connecting to them would be done in an entirely automated fashion, so this wouldn't be an issue?